# Kotlin compose lazyListState scroll

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `lazyColumn` containing a header (image, text,...), some description and then a list of items with a sticky header.
The problem is, even if I add unique keys for each items (in header, description and the list), I can't scroll to a specific item giving its key, I can only scroll to an index of item.

Let's says I want to scroll to item 5 in the list, the generated key will be `item-5`. If I want to scroll to it, I will have to do: `animateScrollToItem({desired_id})` where `desired_id` is computed (sum of header items + description + sticky header + item in list), which is a little bit weird / hard to maintain. Is there any way to create a custom scroll which act like: `animateScrollToItem({desired_key})` where `desired_key` is `item-5` for example?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of item keys in `LazyColumn`or `LazyRow` is to remember the state when recomposing, not to provide compose with an identifier where to scroll to (or similar operations for that matter). Even "worse" for your question, normal columns and rows don't have the concept of an item index, so you'll have to scroll using pixels if you want to scroll to a certain position inside the column.

For `LazyColumn`, you will have to implement a function that scrolls to the given id by yourself, i.e. you pass the key and the full list (or nested lists) and then calculate the position you need to scroll to, using your aforementioned formula.